# attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

A feature of my React Native App consists of making Perspective Corrections to Document Photos.

It takes 4 points, crops the image, perspective corrects it, and then applys CIFilter to adjust the colours and export as Base64 String.

We were trying to run this on an iPhone 11 Simulator

As of now, we have been getting this error

```
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

**Assumption**: It is probably happening because it can't read the image from file storage / the file is being read as `nil`

Here is the source code

```
#import "CustomCropManager.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation CustomCropManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(crop:(NSDictionary *)points imageUri:(NSString *)imageUri callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    NSLog(@"[myLOG] PARSING");

    NSString *parsedImageUri = [imageUri stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] parsedImageUri");


    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:parsedImageUri];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] fileURL");

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage");

    CGPoint newLeft = CGPointMake([points[@"topLeft"][@"x"] floatValue], [points[@"topLeft"][@"y"] floatValue]);
    CGPoint newRight = CGPointMake([points[@"topRight"][@"x"] floatValue], [points[@"topRight"][@"y"] floatValue]);
    CGPoint newBottomLeft = CGPointMake([points[@"bottomLeft"][@"x"] floatValue], [points[@"bottomLeft"][@"y"] floatValue]);
    CGPoint newBottomRight = CGPointMake([points[@"bottomRight"][@"x"] floatValue], [points[@"bottomRight"][@"y"] floatValue]);

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] CGPOINTS");

    newLeft = [self cartesianForPoint:newLeft height:[points[@"height"] floatValue] ];
    newRight = [self cartesianForPoint:newRight height:[points[@"height"] floatValue] ];
    newBottomLeft = [self cartesianForPoint:newBottomLeft height:[points[@"height"] floatValue] ];
    newBottomRight = [self cartesianForPoint:newBottomRight height:[points[@"height"] floatValue] ];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] new");


    NSMutableDictionary *rectangleCoordinates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputTopLeft"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:newLeft];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputTopRight"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:newRight];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputBottomLeft"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:newBottomLeft];
    rectangleCoordinates[@"inputBottomRight"] = [CIVector vectorWithCGPoint:newBottomRight];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] rectangleCoordinates");

    ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIPerspectiveCorrection" withInputParameters:rectangleCoordinates];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage");

     // custom code
     CIFilter* colorControlsFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
     [colorControlsFilter setValue:ciImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
     [colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
[colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2] forKey:@"inputBrightness"];
[colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputContrast"];
    ciImage = [colorControlsFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    // custom code

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage ssss");

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgimage = [context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage];

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] image");

    NSData *imageToEncode = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);

    NSLog(@"[myLOG] calling...");

    callback(@[[NSNull null], @{@"image": [imageToEncode base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]}]);
}

- (CGPoint)cartesianForPoint:(CGPoint)point height:(float)height {
    return CGPointMake(point.x, height - point.y);
}

@end
```

Comment: "Assumption: It is probably happening because it can't read the image from file storage / the file is being read as nil" Ok. What's the nil valu exactly? What are the NSLog printted? Which line is crashing exactly?

Comment: @Larme It is crashing at the line `NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage");` in the debugger, the value of `CIImage *ciImage` is `nil`, but the `NSURL *fileURL` shows a valid file URL

Comment: "the NSURL *fileURL shows a valid file URL ". What does say: "[NSFileManager defautlManager] fileExistsAtURL:fileURL];` or something like that. Because clearly: `[imageUri stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];`, that's not a good way. Could you print the `imageUri`? I'm afraid you keep something wrong, since path might change, and you should go after the UUID generated only.

Answer (score 0):

"Must have 50 reputation to comment"

You should output every variable you are trying to use. Change
`NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage");` to `NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage %@", ciImage);`

If it prints out `NSLog(@"[myLOG] ciImage");` then the crash must happen after that and before the next `NSLog`. Meaning this line fails:

```
[colorControlsFilter setValue:ciImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
```

As you stated the image is `nil` which means the line that set the image contains an error.

```
ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIPerspectiveCorrection" withInputParameters:rectangleCoordinates];
```

Does the filter exist and is written properly?
For debugging purposes you can uncomment this line and see if the original image displays.